# Video file download in background

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, http

I have an iOS application to download multiple videos from server, download only work in background thread, no delay in main UI thread.

Application have an option to download multiple videos, only one download at a time, other request are in queue.

What is the best option to to this?

Now am trying with ASIHTTPRequest. please help.

Comment: I think you should use the BEST library as of now "AFNetworking". https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking Have fun !

Comment: what are the advantage when i move to AFNetworking . for one download i need to send two request.using ASIHTTPRequest startAsynchronous not able to do this.pleas help..

Comment: How does mentioning a library help solving the OPs question? And btw, there are better libraries. ;)